# can't read text in captcha image python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, ocr, recaptcha, python-tesseract

This is my code, I want to read from this captcha image.

[image: Captcha]

```py
screenshot_name = "captcha.png"
driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_name)

#crop img 
img = Image.open("captcha.png")
area = (30, 138, 355, 210)
cropped_img = img.crop(area)
cropped_img.save('captcha1.png')

#read Captcha 

img = cv2.imread("captcha1.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*2, h*2))
cv2.imwrite("captcha2.png",gry)
cls = cv2.morphologyEx(gry, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, None)
thr = cv2.threshold(cls, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imwrite("captcha3.png",thr)
txt = tess.image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
```

I try this code and txt print me nothing, pls help.

Comment: The whole point of captchas is to prove you are not a robot - they are *intended* to be difficult to process by computer.

Comment: As an addition to Mark's comment: You might find a solution for that specific captcha only incorporating simple image-processing methods, but most likely that solution will fail on the next input.

Comment: Extract contours or get each one according an area size